# ROC Curve has good AUC but logistic regression not statistically significant?

Tags: regression, logistic, roc

I ran a logistic regression with 1 predictor for dichotomous outcome, and the predictor was not statistically significant. I ran an ROC curve with the same variable, and got AUC around .70 which is fairly good predictive ability. How do I explain these discrepant results with the same variables?

Comment: Can you provide more details about data and the model.

Comment: Note that the AUC does not really measure "predictive ability". It measures the degree to which the predicted probabilities tend to sort the 1s & 0s.

Answer (score 5):

The most likely reason is that your sample is small.

Statistical significance is not the same as practical importance.  With a large enough N, even a tiny AUC would be significant.  With a small enough N, even an AUC of 0.9 would not be significant.